# How to maintain session at when cookies are disabled in java web application

Tags: java, web-applications

How  to maintain sessionwhen cookies are disabled .When i cleared my history in firefox  the session is expiring.But i dont want to expire the session at client side.What is the way  way to maintain session when cookies are disabled.I am using struts2 .I saw some sites which are doing it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: When history is cleared, the session cookie (received from the server) on the browser is cleared and you cannot send it to the server on the subsequent requests (which is expected). Therefore, you cannot have access to the session on the server (once history is cleared on the browser). What do you want to do with the session on the client side from then onwards?

Comment: Are you saying - what happens, if an obscure browser doesn't support cookies or cookies on the browser are disabled? In which case, the technique called URL rewriting is used.

Comment: ya.That is i am asking

Comment: sorry if i posted in a different way.I corrected my question

Comment: During URL rewriting, instead of exposing the session id as a query string in the URL, appropriate methods should be used to encode URLs. In JSTL, it can be done by using the tag `<c:url>`.

Comment: Why did you quote it? Did you get it from a source?

Comment: which one you are saying

Comment: The text in the question is quoted (enclosed within block quotes). Text needs to be quoted like that in the question when it is from external sources.

Comment: ok ok thank you.I dont know exactly why i need to use this.sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, your session is preserved via cookies. If you delete clear your history, the jsession-cookie is deleted as well.

What you are looking for is Sessionpreservation via URLRewrite. Then the sessionid is attached to every link like

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html;jsessionid=234fds
```

You have to consult the manual of your Servletcontainer/Applicationserver how to enable it.